# How to get GTKSharp TreeView widget to display expanders?

Tags: c#, gtk3, gtk#

So I am creating a treeview selector with C#/GTKSharp. I have the basic tree view selector functionality working: The data is loaded into my model and I can click on a node to collapse/expand.

The part I can't work out is how to tell the cell renderer to display the collapse/expand toggle button. In the examples it appears as a triangle that points right or down depending on whether the node is opened or collapsed. I just have a blank space that works as expected as I click but shows nothing.

One possibility is that I have a white on white text issue but I doubt it as my labels show up fine and I have not done any formatting yet.

I tried adding code for ShowExpanders but that was already true.

```
        TreeView = new Gtk.TreeView();

        // We add the event handlers (i.e. the control part) to the tree
        TreeView.RowActivated += SelectorActivated;         //On double click
        TreeView.Selection.Changed += SelectorSelected;    // On select (single click)
           // Raise a context menu here??
           //  Connect to the ButtonPressEvent 
           //  Raise a popup button

        // Create columns [View]
        Gtk.TreeViewColumn TreeViewColumTitle = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
        TreeViewColumTitle.Title = "Profile";
        Gtk.CellRendererText NameCellTitle = new Gtk.CellRendererText();

        TreeViewColumTitle.PackStart(NameCellTitle, true);
        TreeViewColumTitle.SetCellDataFunc(NameCellTitle, new Gtk.TreeCellDataFunc(RenderTitle));


        NameCellTitle.Mode = CellRendererMode.Activatable;

        // Populate the model
        // Note that we could dispense with this step if we generated an ITreeModel
        // interface in the Object class.
        BindModel(Model);

        // Attach everything to the pane
        TreeView.Model = GTKModel;
        TreeView.AppendColumn(TreeViewColumTitle);
        TreeView.ShowExpanders = true;
        TreeView.ExpanderColumn.Visible = true;
```

...

```
    private void BindModel(Model Model) {
        GTKModel = new Gtk.TreeStore(typeof(Object));
        foreach (Object Object in Model.Selector) {
            var BindingData = new BindingDataGTK(this, Object);
            BindingData.Iter = GTKModel.AppendValues(Object);
            Object.BindingData = BindingData;
            BindChildren(GTKModel, BindingData);
            }
        }

    private void BindChildren(TreeStore TreeStore, BindingDataGTK ObjectBinding) {

        foreach (var Child in ObjectBinding.Object) {
            var BindingData = new BindingDataGTK(this, Child);
            BindingData.Iter = TreeStore.AppendValues(ObjectBinding.Iter, Child);
            Child.BindingData = BindingData;
            BindChildren(TreeStore, BindingData);
            }
        }


    private void RenderTitle(Gtk.TreeViewColumn Column, Gtk.CellRenderer Cell, 
                        Gtk.ITreeModel GTKModel, Gtk.TreeIter Iter) {
        Object Object = (Object)GTKModel.GetValue(Iter, 0);
        (Cell as Gtk.CellRendererText).Text = Object.Title;


        Console.WriteLine("Render {0}", Object.Title);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know this is pretty much an automatic feature, I don't think anything special is needed to make it happen (I've certainly never needed to). You might want to try using a TreeIter to construct your tree instead?

E.g. assuming you already have a TreeView on your form with 0 (zero) columns in it called "treeview" and a list of "MyObject"s called "myListOfObjects"...

```
treeview.AppendColumn ("Some Title", new CellRendererText(), "text", 0);
Gtk.TreeStore _ts = new TreeStore (typeof(string));
foreach (IMyObject _mo in myListOfObjects) {
    Gtk.TreeIter _it = _ts.AppendValues (_mo.SomeText);
    RecurseInto (_ts, _it, _mo);
}
treeview.Model = _ts;

...

void RescureInto(Gtk.TreeStore ts, Gtk.TreeIter it, IMyObject mo)
{
    foreach (IMyObject _child_mo in mo.Children) {
        Gtk.TreeIter _it = ts.AppendValues (it, _child_mo.SomeText);
        RecurseInto (ts, _it, _child_mo);
    }
}
```

In theory this should work fine.